# Android soft keyboard showing under a dialog fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, keyboard

I have a dialog fragment, which has a listview with mutiple views listed, in one of that view there is an edittext which has showing cursor, but soft keyboard is not showing. 
So i write a code on its onclick to show keyboard like below,

```
etcomment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity
                            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                }
            });
```

Now keyboard is showing, but it is showing under that `DialogFragment`

[image]

I searched but didn't get an answer, please help me!

Comment: try this dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

Comment: already tried!! but keyboard is not showing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your window params is the problem Okay u should do like this:..

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DialogTestKeyboard.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width  = 400;
    lp.height = 800;
    dialog.setContentView(yourLayoutHavingEditText);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    dialog.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I have a layout which has edit text in that layout and i am setting this for dialog and when i remove the last line the keyboard goes back like urs but when i include the line it comes in front...